# Spring successful login results in js/bootstrap.min.js displayed

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with Spring security for authentication.  I have a layout.html page for use by my other pages.

When I go to my login.html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="layout :: head">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="padding-top:60px;">
....
</div>
<div th:include="layout :: foot"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Where here is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<body>

<div th:fragment="head" class="my-header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-transparent" role="navigation">
...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The form submits a POST, which returns a 302:
[image]

And then the url is redirected to http://localhost:9001/js/bootstrap.min.js instead of http://localhost:9001/  so that the browser just shows the contents of the bootstrap js file.  If I manually change the URL to http://localhost:9001 then my authenticated window is shown.   All other pages behave normally, its just the login page that shows the js file content.

I cannot figure out where the call to display js/bootstrap.min.js is coming from, I grep'd my files and all references to it are in the format:

```
<script src="/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your time in reading this and offering any advice on what might be causing this issue.

Comment: What are the contents of your spring-security file?

Comment: The user authentication is stored in a db.  But the authentication is successful if that is what you are wondering.

Comment: What are the values of login-processing-url, default-target-url, authentication-failure-url?

Comment: I use JavaConfig to handle this.  But after you question, I went in and added `.antMatchers( "/js/**" ).permitAll()` to my ` @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http....}` and that appears to have fixed the problem.  Weird.  Thank you for helping me point in the right direction.